# PL/SQL cursor for loop doing 1 too few loops

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need a pl sql procedure that outputs all of the books in a database that meet certain criteria. I've got it running and outputting correct values, however it always leaves 1 set of values off. For example, if I run it with certain constraints that would return 10 books, my procedure only shows 9. And it is always the book that would have been at the bottom of the list. Any help is appreciated.

```
create or replace procedure which_titles(quant_limit number, price_limit number) as
begin
    for next_title in (select *
                       from title)
    loop
      IF next_title.qty_on_hand <= quant_limit
         and next_title.title_price <= price_limit THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(next_title.title_name || ' - ' || next_title.qty_on_hand || ' - ' || next_title.title_price);
      END IF;
    end loop;
end;
/
show errors
```

Comment: The `IF` statement is not required. Use `select * from title where qty_on_hand <= quant_limit and title_price <= price_limit` and see how many rows it returns

Comment: Why aren't you doing the filtering inside the cursor query? It would be more efficient, but it would also be easier for you to run the same query stand-alone and figure out why it isn't doing what you expect. You would see you'd only get 9 rows back. The loop isn't missing one, but your `if` might be excluding it. Without the data and parameters we can't say where your mistake is though.

Comment: There isn't anything in this loop which would cause this kind of "off-by-one" error; therefore, I suspect there's something in the data which is causing this problem. Please edit your question to include a sample of the data, including all relevant fields (QTY_ONHAND, TITLE_PRICE, TITLE_NAME). Thanks.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `select qty_on_hand, title_price from title` as well as the values of `quant_limit` and `price_limit`?  That would reveal the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the code posted. It seems ok. Only theres some redundancy in code that has be modified. Also the secret lies in the SELECT Query mostly. So run the select query with actual input outside the procedure. You will definitly get your query resolved.

Hope this helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
procedure which_titles(
    quant_limit IN  NUMBER,
    price_limit IN  NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR next_title IN
  (SELECT         *
  FROM title
  WHERE title.qty_on_hand <= quant_limit
  AND title.title_price   <= price_limit
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(next_title.title_name || ' - ' || next_title.qty_on_hand || ' - ' || next_title.title_price);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```